# Print rows whose first field appears exactly twice in the file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this:

```
91052011868;Export Equi_Fort Postal;EXPORT;23/02/2015;1;0;0
91052011868;Sof_equi_Fort_Email_am_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%;EMAIL;19/02/2015;1;0;0
91052011868;Sof_trav_Fort_Email_am_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%;EMAIL;19/02/2015;1;0;0
91052151371;Export Trav_faible temoin;EXPORT;12/02/2015;1;0;0
91052182019;Export Deme_fort temoin;EXPORT;24/02/2015;1;0;0
91052199517;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_pm;EMAIL;22/01/2015;1;0;0
91052199517;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_Relance_pm;EMAIL;26/01/2015;1;0;0
91052262558;Sof_deme_faible_Email_am;EMAIL;26/01/2015;1;0;1
91052265940;Sof_trav_Faible_Email_am_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%;EMAIL;13/02/2015;1;0;0
91052265940;Sof_trav_Faible_Email_Relance_am_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%;EMAIL;17/02/2015;1;0;0
91052265940;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_am_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%;EMAIL;13/02/2015;1;0;0
91052265940;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%;EMAIL;16/02/2015;1;0;0
91052531428;Export Trav_faible temoin;EXPORT;11/02/2015;1;0;0
91052547697;Export Deme_Faible Postal;EXPORT;27/02/2015;1;0;0
91052562398;Export Deme_faible temoin;EXPORT;18/02/2015;1;0;0
```

I want to know all the lines where the first column duplicated values are greater than 1 but strictly inferior to 3.

```
91052199517;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_pm;EMAIL;22/01/2015;1;0;0
91052199517;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_Relance_pm;EMAIL;26/01/2015;1;0;0
```

I did the part below but it doesn't work...

```
 sort file | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}{ if (a[$1] > 0 && a[$1] <1 )print $0;}' file file
```

Why?

Comment: it is not very clear what you mean. You have been asking many questions and we tend to amend our answers over and over again until we find the exact point. What if you "debug" your question so that it is clear from the first moment?

Comment: @fedorqui. lol. my bad. Let me try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: @fedorqui , does it make sense now?

Comment: So you want to know all those first fields appearing twice?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, twice in my example. But I also need to know in case they are appearing 3 times or 4. I thought my script was correct but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `greater than 1 but strictly inferior to 3` is a very odd way of saying `equal to 2`.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, I guess saying equal to 2 is the best way. I'm always trying to make it more complex than what is needed. Bad habit, I cannot get rid of.

Comment: Computing Science is not a science. You can tell because it has the word "Science" in the title, just like all the other non-sciences (Political Science, Social Science, etc.). The real sciences like Physics and Chemistry do not have that suffix. The point is - this is art, not science, and as such there's many ways to express yourself and you just have to try to find the way that "feels right" ... :-).

Comment: @EdMorton Very interesting comment and true. I did not think about it but now that you've mentionned it. :)

Comment: @fedorqui I did not have the time to mention it but your profile picture of Noodles is just great . :)

Comment: Yeah! One of the top top movies ever, and De Niro is superb :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to print all those lines whose first field appears twice, you can use this:

```
$ awk -F";" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++; next} a[$1]==2' file file
91052199517;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_pm;EMAIL;22/01/2015;1;0;0
91052199517;Sof_voya_Faible_Email_Relance_pm;EMAIL;26/01/2015;1;0;0
```

This sets the field separator to the semi colon and then reads the file twice:
- the first time to count how many the 1st field appears (`a[$1]++`) 
- the second time to print those lines matching the condition `a[$1]==2`. That is, the first field to appearing twice throughout the file.

If you wanted those indexes appearing between 2 and 4 times, you could use the following syntax on the second block:

```
a[$1]>=2 && a[$1]<=4
```

---

#### Why wasn't your approach working?

Because your condition says:

```
if (a[$1] > 0 && a[$1] <1 )
```

which of course will never happen, since `a[$1]` is an integer and no integer is bigger than 0 and smaller than 1.

Note my proposed solution uses the same idea, only that in a bit more idiomatic way: There is no need to be explicit in the `if` condition, neither saying `print $0`: this is exactly what `awk` does when a condition evaluates as True.

Comment: Trying to be as precise as possible but it is not an easy task. But let's try again until I get there. Many thanks.

Comment: You are getting there. Just try to remember what [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says: "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence".